# Is there a version of brunch for a meal between dinner and lunch?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, time, food

Brunch has become quite a common word in the English language. Is there a similar word for a meal in place of dinner and lunch? (A phrase will also do).

Comment: "Lunner" or "dinch" :)

Comment: I thought "tea time" served the Brits in that capacity.

Comment: [Dinner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinner) has traditionally been the largest meal of the day, whatever time it is eaten

Comment: What about Elevenses? Luncheon? Afternoon tea? Dinner? Supper? He knows about them, doesn't he?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In US English, an *afternoon snack* is the best term I know of.

In the UK, there are lots of options, but they’re fraught with geographic and social connotations.

***Afternoon tea*** will be understood everywhere, but seen in some places as upper-class; it’s traditionally not a full meal, but just eg a piece of cake or a sandwich and a cup of tea or coffee.

***High tea*** is probably most analogous to brunch; it’s a light early-evening meal, usually had instead of rather than as well as dinner, and like with brunch/breakfast, someone who eats *dinner* or *supper* most evenings might well have *high tea* instead once in a while.  *High tea* also has slight upper-class connotations in some areas, I think, but not everywhere.

***Tea*** on its own can mean many things; to many people in the Midlands and the north of England, it means something like this, the main evening meal, but typically eaten rather earlier in the evening than people who call it *dinner* would eat.  This usage used to have strong working-class connotations in the past, but now is more of a geographical distinction, I think.

While on the subject, there’s also ***supper***; for some people again, *supper* means the main meal of the evening (I was brought up that way), while for others, who had probably *dinner* or *high tea* as their main meal, it’s a late-evening snack.

This is a run-down off the top of my head; there are almost certainly some nuances and distinctions I’ve missed.  Whole dissertations have probably been written on the hermeneutics of English mealtime terminology…

Comment: *Whole dissertations have probably been written on the hermeneutics of English mealtime terminology...* Haha, not at all hard to believe. Regional differences abound—what a beautiful world of English!

Comment: I take my meal cues from the Hobbits. They have seven meals a day: breakfast, second breakfast(my favorite), elevensies, luncheon, afternoon tea, dinner and supper.

Comment: I grew up in Boston and supper was the word for everyday dinner at home, and dinner was for when you go out, or a fancy dinner at home

Comment: How dare you elide 'English mealtime terminology' and 'UK English'! Scottish meals have an entirely different terminology, and as for Northern Ireland... There is scope for a monograph on these vocabulary differences, but I think perhpas an American should not be the one to write it.

Comment: @TimLymington: I didn’t mean to conflate those in the least; I wrote what I know (I’m half-Londoner, half-Yorkie), and I hope I qualified it all enough to make clear I wasn’t claiming comprehensiveness.  I’ve never spent long enough in Scotland to get to know the different options there, so I’d be very interested to hear about them.

Answer (score 4):

There is no single mixed word along the lines of *brunch* for this. Sometimes people joke by coining a mixture of *lunch* and *dinner/supper*, giving *lupper, dunch,* etc. (As Kosmonaut mentioned.)

You might refer to a small afternoon meal as *afternoon tea*, though to me (American) this sounds British and upper-class. Otherwise you'd probably just call it a *snack* or a *late lunch*, if it's bigger than a snack.

Comment: *Lunch*, *dupper*, hehe. I like that!

Comment: A meal in-between Lunch and Super is called Sunch.

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on where you live, [*dinner*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1240464#m_en_us1240464) could be a midday, late-afternoon/early-evening, or late-night meal. *Lunch* is usually a midday meal. In reality, there is no word for a meal *in place of* lunch and dinner (I assume you use *dinner* to mean an evening meal after a midday lunch.)

Dinner could be the main meal of your day, and whether you have it at noon, two o'clock, five o'clock, or eight o'clock, it remains your dinner. If you are going to have a substantial meal after breakfast, with only a very late snack in view before bed, then that meal becomes your dinner, no matter how weird that sounds.

I should point out, though, that in this day and age, especially for the yuppies, formal mealtimes may not be the norm. Plus, the usage of *dinner* for a midday or mid-afternoon meal, and other such formalisms as *tea*, etc, may now be considered quite old-fashioned. Thus, I would recommend sticking with either **late lunch** or **early dinner** for this particular situation.

Comment: You are right about the lack of formal mealtimes. I was having my first bite of the day at 4 PM.